# c# uwp templatebinding and dependency property

Tags: c#, binding, uwp, dependency-properties, templatebinding

In UWP I am trying to change default template of tooltip.

I have managed it, but now I need to set tooltip arrow to point out to the control it belongs to.

My style is defined as this:

```
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToolTipBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Roboto" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ToolTipContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="40,40,40,35"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">

                    <Grid Background="Transparent">

                        <Grid 
                            MinWidth="100"
                            MinHeight="90"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                            Padding="15" 
                            Background="Transparent">
```

And so on and on...

But now I am trying to make UserControl bind with TemplateBinding property.

I have created UserControl that have some dependecncy property.
Like this:

```
    public PlacementMode TooltipPlacement
    {
        get { return (PlacementMode)GetValue(TooltipPlacementProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TooltipPlacementProperty, value);  CalculateArrowVisibility(); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TooltipPlacementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TooltipPlacement", typeof(PlacementMode), typeof(ArrowDown), null);
```

CalculateArrowVisibility() is a method that will calculate the arrow location depending on TooltipPlacement.

And that control is in style defined as this:

```
<local:ArrowDown x:Name="arrow" TooltipPlacement="{TemplateBinding Placement}"/>
```

But it is not bound, I have tried other TemplateProperties but no luck also.

Where is the problem here?

Comment: What is `Content` in `TooltipPlacement="{TemplateBinding Content}"`?

Comment: I have mistake during copy-paste...it should be:
<local:ArrowDown x:Name="arrow" TooltipPlacement="{TemplateBinding Placement}"/>

Comment: What is `SetValue()` in `set { SetValue(TooltipPlacementProperty, value); SetValue(); }`? Is it a Function overload to do someother operation?

Comment: That is a method that will be executed after bind set the property value. In that method I will put logic for calculating the arrow visibility.

Comment: As far as I understand DataBinding is not working for `TooltipPlacement`. Am I right? Also, Add your last comment in your question

Comment: I have edited it. So, do you know any alternative for setting this value?

Comment: Your method is correct. Since there is no entire code for your CustomControl I can't debug it. If you like you can provide some additional code. Did you try to debug using BreakPoint?

Comment: Yeah, and the execution of app is not stopped by BreakPoints.

Comment: You can use `<ArrowDown TooltipPlacement="{Binding Placement, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource ArrowDown}">` if you want an alternative way to set TemplateBinding.

Comment: > execution of app is not stopped by BreakPoints, Why?

Comment: Because it is not entering the binding part.

Comment: And when I add <ArrowDown TooltipPlacement="{Binding Placement, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource ArrowDown}"> , I get the error message Failed to create a 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.RelativeSource' from the text 'ArrowDown'. [Line: 67 Position: 55]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close excpet the way you delcare the dependency property is wrong.

You should never modify its getter and setter. Instead, call your `CalculateArrowVisibility` method inside its property changed callback like this -

```
public PlacementMode TooltipPlacement
{
    get => (PlacementMode)GetValue(TooltipPlacementProperty);
    set => SetValue(TooltipPlacementProperty, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty TooltipPlacementProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("TooltipPlacement", typeof(PlacementMode), typeof(ArrowDown), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null, TooltipPlacementChangedCallback));

private static void TooltipPlacementChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var self = (ArrowDown)d;
    self.CalculateArrowVisibility();
}
```

Comment: But anyway the binding part is not executed. I have put breaking points to check, and no luck.

Comment: @user3239349 you must have done something wrong somewhere else. I created a project exactly like how you described n it worked fine. Either edit the question with more code or provide me a repo so I can test.

Comment: With editing the dependency property your way it is working now. Thanx, that was the only problem in my code.

Comment: And do you maybe know why PlacementMode is always Top, no matter if tooltip is shown under or above control?

Comment: Maybe there's not enough room on the bottom? Anyway, could you post another question with more details?

Comment: I will put another question. No, there is enough room for it to be shown, sometimes it shows under sometimes above control, just the property I am updating in ArrowDown control (TooltipPlacement) via style is always Top.

Comment: Here is the question link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44881804/c-sharp-uwp-tooltip-placement-property-not-updating

Comment: I will have a look.