# c# uwp tooltip placement property not updating

Tags: c#, uwp, tooltip, dependency-properties, templatebinding

In C# UWP I am creating custom tooltip style.

I have changed the default style of tooltip as below.

```
    <Style TargetType="ToolTip">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeMediumLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundChromeHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource ToolTipBorderThemeThickness}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ToolTipContentThemeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="40,40,40,35"/>

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">

                    <Grid Background="Transparent">

                        <Grid 
                            MinWidth="100"
                            MinHeight="90"
                            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
                            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" 
                            Padding="15" 
                            Background="Transparent">

                         <local:ArrowDown  x:Name="arrowDown" TooltipPlacement="{TemplateBinding Placement}"/>
```

And my custom control ArrowDown is getting information of ToolTip placement, so I can show it depends if tooltip is under or above control.

In the ArrowDown control I have added a DependencyProperty as below:

```
    public PlacementMode TooltipPlacement
    {
        get { return (PlacementMode)GetValue(TooltipPlacementProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TooltipPlacementProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TooltipPlacementProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TooltipPlacement", typeof(PlacementMode), typeof(ArrowDown), new PropertyMetadata(null, TooltipPlacementChangedCallback));

    private static void TooltipPlacementChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var self = (ArrowDown)d;
        self.CalculateArrowVisibility();
    }

    // Method to show or hide arrow
    private void CalculateArrowVisibility()
    {
    }
```

And the problem is that the CalculateArrowVisibility is fire only the first time when tooltip is shown, and it always returns Top for TooltipPlacement, no matter if tooltip is shown below or above control.

I need CalculateArrowVisibility to be fired whenever the tooltip is shown, and I need TooltipPlacement property to show if tooltip is Under or Above control.

Anyone have the idea about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact is that you cannot use the `ToolTipService` attached properties (e.g.         `<Button ToolTipService.Placement="Bottom" ToolTipService.ToolTip="!!!" />`) to define the tooltip and it placement. This way the `Placement` is not set on the actual `ToolTip` control itself, and that's why it will always return `Top`.

In order to have the `ToolTip` pass down its `Placement` value to your custom dependency property, you will have to attach it like the following -

```
<Button>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Placement="Bottom" Content="Hahaha..." />
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>
```

---

### Update

Turns out that even though the app Window pushes the tooltip above or below its parent, its `Placement` value is never changed, what's changed is its horizontal & vertical offsets.

So, in your case, if we could work out its exact vertical offset, we would be able to determine whether the tooltip is above or below (its parent).

Given we have a `ToolTip` *Style* in place, we can create an attached property of type `ToolTip` and attach it to the `Grid` that contains the `ArrowDown` control.

```
<Grid MinWidth="100"
      MinHeight="90"
      Height="{TemplateBinding Height}"
      Width="{TemplateBinding Width}"
      Padding="15"
      Background="Transparent"
      local:ToolTipHelper.ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
```

Because the `TemplatedParent` of the `Grid` is the `ToolTip`, we can use `RelativeSource` binding to link the `ToolTip` on the screen with our attached property, as shown above.

Now, we have a reference to the actual `ToolTip`, let's find its offsets. After some digging, I've found that the offsets of the `ToolTip` are always `0`, they are useless; however, the offsets of its parent - a `Popup`, sometimes gives me the correct values, but not always. This is because I was using the `Opened` event where those values weren't yet populated; as soon as I changed it to `SizeChanged`, they have been giving me the expected values.

```
public static class ToolTipHelper
{
    public static ToolTip GetToolTip(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ToolTip)obj.GetValue(ToolTipProperty);
    }
    public static void SetToolTip(DependencyObject obj, ToolTip value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ToolTipProperty, value);
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ToolTipProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ToolTip", typeof(ToolTip), typeof(ToolTipHelper), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null, (s, e) =>
        {
            var panel = (Panel)s; // The Grid that contains the ArrowDown control.
            var toolTip = (ToolTip)e.NewValue;

            // We need to monitor SizeChanged instead of Opened 'cause the offsets
            // are yet to be properly set in the latter event.
            toolTip.SizeChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var popup = (Popup)toolTip.Parent; // The Popup that contains the ToolTip.

                // Note we have to use the Popup's offset here as the ToolTip's are always 0.
                var arrowDown = (ArrowDown)panel.FindName("arrowDown");
                arrowDown.TooltipPlacement = popup.VerticalOffset > 0
                    ? PlacementMode.Bottom
                    : PlacementMode.Top;
            };
        }));
}
```

Now, with this approach, you should be able to use the `ToolTipService` attached properties too. So the following XAML would work.

```
<Button ToolTipService.ToolTip="!!!" Content="Hover Me" />
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And what if tooltip is set automatically?

Comment: What do you mean? What is set automatically?

Comment: Well, if the placement of tooltip is not set in xaml, and tooltip is shows above or below, depends on if there is a place to be shown.
<Button>
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Content="Hahaha..." />
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Button>

Like this.

Comment: It should be set properly. But you should be able to test it out, right?

Comment: Well, I set the Placement="Top", and if I move the window to the top of the Screen, the tooltip will be shown under the control, and again the Property TooltipPlacement will be Top.

Comment: And, it is really getting the real tooltip placement now, with this <ToolTip Placement="Bottom" Content="Hahaha..." />, but it's just the problem now is that if it changed it's placement while user use the app, it will not fire the binding.

Comment: OK, I don't think the `Placement` of the tooltip is changing at all... There might be something else that affects its position, but the `Placement` value is definitely unchanged. So you will need to find another way to tell whether it's on top or bottom. I also tried the offset values but they are very inconsistent so you can't rely on them either... You might be able to however, find the position relative to the parent control, so you can work out whether it's above or below it.

Comment: Yes, I will try some workaround. Thanx for the tips, anyway, it gave me some ideas.

Comment: No worries. Actually, I think I have a solution. Will post it soon.

Comment: Yes, this is it! Thanx! :)

Comment: I have been testing this, and it seems that VerticalOffset is getting larger each time it is shown on another control. Also, it acts differently depending if control is in the up corner, or if control is in the center of screen. In slider it is reverted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148291/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-user3239349).